# Is there a way to rewrite naked domain url in html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, url-rewriting

Trying to rewrite https://example.com with / (like https://example.com/) or without / at the end, to https://example.com/hello

Is it possible with javascript inside html? Don't want to rewrite any other matches

Comment: Can you give context? or you just want to change the URL the user sees

Comment: App only works with context root in url like https://example.com/hello. Want users to get to it with naked domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the window.history.pushState function.
here's an example for that

```
const state = { 'page_id': 1, 'user_id': 5 }
const title = 'NEW TITLE'
const url = 'https://example.com/hello'

window.history.pushState(state, title, url)
```

more data an examples in this link
 [example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-modify-url-without-reloading-the-page-using-javascript/).